# Logical OR in Regex while detecting Year and Months

Tags: python, regex

I want to find Month and year ranges in a String, i've tried the following Regex.

```
(\b\d{1,2}\D{0,3})?\b(?:jan(?:uary)?|feb(?:ruary)?|mar(?:ch)?|apr(?:il)?|may|jun(?:e)?|jul(?:y)?|aug(?:ust)?|sep(?:tember)?|oct(?:ober)?|(nov|dec)(?:ember)?)\D?(\d{1,2}(st|nd|rd|th)?)?(([,.\-\/])\D?)?((19[7-9]\d|20\d{2})|\d{2})*
```

Although it works really good, but it is not able to detect patterns like '1993 - 2018'. i know `((19[7-9]\d|20\d{2})|\d{2})*` will find the following pattern, but i don't know how to create logical **`OR`** to do this, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note a direct answer but it does seem like you might want to take a look at [`python-dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: you already used or with `|`

Comment: @prhmma i know, i've tried to do it myself, unfortunately i was not able to do it

Comment: Please provide a collection of inputs and the desired list of what should match within them. Your regex matches days yet you don't talk about them in your text.